# SQL INNER JOIN two arrays of values from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, set, intersection

I have a simplified query where I just need to get the intersection of two arrays. When there is a positive intersection, I am getting the expected result returned. But if there is no result, I get all rows returned from the entire table, as opposed to the expected zero rows.

This is one query where I get one row returned, as expected:

```
SELECT ID FROM table_name WHERE ID IN (7188,2442,10350) AND ID IN (10350,6936)
```

It returns one row with the ID 10350, as expected.

But if I try this query:

```
SELECT ID FROM table_name WHERE ID IN (7188,2442) AND ID IN (10350,6936)
```

it returns the entire table, instead of zero rows.

Clearly, my syntax is incorrect, but I don't know how to write the proper query that will find the intersection of two arrays. Can I please find out how to write such an intersection the correct way? Please notice that this is only one table (as opposed to an INNER JOIN from multiple tables). I have to use multiple arrays as the sets to be compared.

I've searched SO and Google for a long time, but nothing seems to come up. It seems like there should be a simple answer to this.

Comment: Please post  CREATE statement, INSERT statement with sample data and the version of your server.

Comment: So you are going to be providing a list/array and another, different, list/array where you need the ID field to exist in both list/arrays?

Comment: I cannot replicate this finding

Comment: Me neither: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/po7vGB4qRdryYu6x1WiLAd/0

Answer (score 1):

I was running this query and getting an empty result after all. But then I sent the result immediately to a WordPress function, which happens to return all rows if you call an empty array as one of the values in $args.

When I saw your comments that the finding wasn't being replicated, I realized I needed to isolate the problem further. So those comments helped me solve the problem.